# GPS using Qt Mobility

Tags: c++, qt, qt-mobility

Am new to Qt and am a bit lost ...

I just want to include the following:

```
#include <QGeoPositionInfo>
```

this is my .pro file:

```
# Add files and directories to ship with the application 
# by adapting the examples below.
# file1.source = myfile
# dir1.source = mydir
DEPLOYMENTFOLDERS = # file1 dir1

symbian:TARGET.UID3 = 0xEF75C11C

# Smart Installer package's UID
# This UID is from the protected range 
# and therefore the package will fail to install if self-signed
# By default qmake uses the unprotected range value if unprotected UID is defined for the application
# and 0x2002CCCF value if protected UID is given to the application
#symbian:DEPLOYMENT.installer_header = 0x2002CCCF

# Allow network access on Symbian
symbian:TARGET.CAPABILITY += NetworkServices

# If your application uses the Qt Mobility libraries, uncomment
# the following lines and add the respective components to the 
# MOBILITY variable. 
 QT += network

 CONFIG += mobility
 MOBILITY +=systeminfo

SOURCES += main.cpp mainwindow.cpp \
    form.cpp \
    form1.cpp
HEADERS += mainwindow.h \
    form.h \
    form1.h
FORMS += mainwindow.ui \
    form.ui \
    form1.ui


# Please do not modify the following two lines. Required for deployment.
include(deployment.pri)
qtcAddDeployment()

OTHER_FILES +=

RESOURCES += \
    karim.qrc
```

and i got the following error

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\karim\Qt\Project-build-simulator\..\Project\form1.h:3: error: QGeoPositionInfo: No such file or directory
```

am a bit lost , My Question are the following:

**Does Qt Mobility come by default with the Qt SDK ?**

**If yes , its should be a matter in the code ? can you please tell me what did i do wrong ?**

## please be specific in your answers , i would appreciate that...

Comment: `MOBILITY+= location systeminfo` . You might also need to add `QTM_USE_NAMESPACE` to the beginning of your source or header file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you built and installed the Mobility API Package?
http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility/installation.html

And you also need the MOBILITY += location on the .pro file.